# choose the coorect option $1)$ $K$ is uncountable $2)$ $K$ is finite.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded set. Let $H(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of all entire functions and let $C(K)$ denote the set of all continuous functions on $K$. Consider the restriction map $r:H(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow C(K)$ by $r(f)=f|_K.$ Then $r$ is injective if

then  choose the coorect option

$1)$ $K$ is uncountable

$2)$ $K$ is finite.

My attempt  :  $K$ must be finite  because  $K$ is bounded as  we know that  bounded set  are  generally  countable set  so , option $1)$  is false

Is its   True ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Why are bounded sets countable?

Comment: bounded set  is  finite  so it  can be   countable   @anomaly

Comment: No, a bounded set is not necessarily finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

First, why your attempt is wrong. $K$ could be infinite and uncountable, take the set of real numbers $[0, 1]$ for example.

Because it's asking if $r$ is injective, you could take a look at the cardinality of the sets $H(\mathbb{C})$ and $C(K)$.

Comment: can u give me the example  of  $H( \mathbb{C})$ ?

Comment: I don't actually know how you would calculate the cardinality of $H(\mathbb{C})$, but we can safely say it's infinite. 
(1) If $K$ is uncountable, $C(K)$ would be infinite.
(2) If $K$ is finite,  $C(K)$ would be finite as well since it's just the set of all permutations of $K$.
Obviously if $C(K)$ is finite $r$ is definitely not an injection, so choose (1)